# Where is MSBuild.exe in SonarScanner for .NET?

Tags: sonarqube

I am following the [official SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-dotnet/) to run sonarscanner for a `.net framework` solution. I managed to run the first command `SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"project-key" /d:sonar.token="myAuthenticationToken"` but stuck at second command, `MSBuild.exe <path to the project file or .sln file> /t:Rebuild`. Does anyone know where `MSBuild.exe` is located?

[image]